# Relationship between poisson and gamma

Tags: poisson-distribution, exponential-distribution

Supposing that I have an interval $n$ units long with $m$ arrivals, and I model arrival using a poisson distribution with $\lambda = m/n$, it's pretty easy to show that the distance between successive arrivals has an exponential distribution $\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$.

However, I'm having a hard time generalizing this to a variation of the gamma distribution when I want to look more than $2$ arrivals (say I have $3$ successive or four successive arrivals). Can someone explain the logic there?

I believe the density should be $\frac{\lambda^{k-1}} {(k-1)!} x^{k-2}e^{-\lambda x}$ but I am not sure how!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum of independent Gamma random variables with the same scale factor (equivalently, same rate factor) is a Gamma random variable with the same scale factor, and the order is the sum of the orders.  See, for example, [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/27908/6633).  So, apply this to your problem using the fact that exponential random variables are Gamma random variables of order $1$. Your density is not quite right, 
by the way: it should be
$$\frac{\lambda(\lambda x)^{k-1}}{\Gamma(k)}\exp(-\lambda x) = 
\frac{\lambda^{k}x^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}\exp(-\lambda x)~~ \text{for}~ x>0.$$

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I needed. The paper here: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1950645/ threw me a bit with formula 1 (since it showed my density) but after reading your's I realized that they are summing only k-1 terms. Thanks again.